# How to tell Magento that there is new block available, so that it can be used in a template with ->getChildHtml('name_of_that_block')

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, template

How to tell Magento that there is new block available, so that it can be used in a template with
`<?php $this->getChildHtml('name_of_that_block'); ?>`?
I want to pull in my Block and template defined in my module to another template to be used as a child. How do I do this?

Comment: You need create in layout a block type core/text_list with name "name_of_that_block" for rendering

Comment: you can '<block type="core/text_list" name="newBlock" as="newBlock"/>'  in your layout file ,  and "echo $this->getChildHtml('newBlock')"

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar I created layout_updates.xml in the module root folder. I put the updates in this file, but they are not taken, it seems. In config.xml for the module I did this: 
<frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <thinkopen_promocarousel>
                    <file>layout_updates.xml</file>
                </thinkopen_promocarousel>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
Is this correct?

Comment: Please give an answer if you'd like. Comment is not very useful otherwise. Thanks

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic include code of what have you tried

Comment: I resolved the issue. I had the wrongly named etc/modules/namespace_module.xml file.